# How can I describe this alien-looking sculpture art style / concept to find other examples?

Tags: sculpting, style-identification

I want to make a sculpture of an abstract, alien-looking, spiky, liquid-like solid object (I don't know how to properly describe it) like in the screenshot below.

[image: taken from stellaris game]

What is this style / concept of design called? Or if it had no name, how can I properly describe this style so I can look it up in search engine?
I want to find more references on that object for inspiration.
I've tried using the keywords above but they yielded no result. English is not my main language so my vocabulary isn't wide enough to get what I need.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Organic Kinetic Futurist Sculpture

Adding *organic* and *kinetic* gives [many similar results](https://www.google.com/search?q=organic%20kinetic%20futuristic%20sculpture&rlz=1C5MACD_enFR506FR507&sxsrf=ACYBGNRZGNv0n4W0IKlNuz4mTaOaC-Dwfw:1569161430228&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjxiJPtzeTkAhUHEBQKHY6zARwQ_AUIEigB&biw=1947&bih=1217) like the sculptures of [Patrice Pit Hubert](http://www.1661235.com/Patrice_%22pit%22_hubert._sculptor/news.html)

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly what i'm after. God bless you.

Answer (score 0):

You could file that under "Abstract Expressionism"
  "Surreal Expressionism" "Futuristic Conceptual"
✌

Comment: If nobody's said it yet, welcome to Arts & Crafts.  Your answer could well be correct (it's out of my area, so I don't have a clue).  But it got bumped to a [review queue](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/4988) because of its brevity.  Ideally, answers should be a little more educational, explaining not just what the answer is but why.  As is, this is sort of just a hint.  The reader would need to do their own research to know if you are right, and create their own answer.  Compare this to Danielillo's answer.  (cont'd)

Comment: The images illustrate how and why that answer is correct.  Readers can instantly see the similarities and know how good a match it is.  If you could add some examples from each style that are similar to those in the question, that would be a big improvement.  Just store the images on a public sharing site, like imgur.com, and post links to them.  Some one here will embed them for you.

Comment: Thanks for the information I absolutely understand,and will do that from now on.My apologies for the delayed response , I've been fighting with "Aloha" browser and configuration for full integration due to some data issue's through list file's,but I digress.Thank you again!✌️